# Titanium Ipad: How to restrict the textbox to allow specific format

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile

I am new to Titanium. I am developing an ipap app using titanium. My app needs a textbox that allow only 1234AA or 1234 AA format.(AA/aa). i want to display a message under textbox "Invalid format: 1234 AA" while entering text in texbox.it should disappear after correct format is entered. I searched on google but i didn't find anything. 
 how to write the code for this?
Thanks!

I tried in another way that: I added a eventlistener 'click' to a button with code

```
    submit.addeventlistener('click',function(){
          pattern="[0-9]{4}\s?[A-Za-z]{2}";
           var textfieldvalue=textfield.value;
           if(!textfieldvalue.match(pattern))
            {
                 var errorlabel=Ti.UI.createlabel({color:'black',text:'Invalid format:
                                                    1234AB'...});
                    win.add(error);
              }
             else{
                 //opening other window
                 }
         });
```

its working but text box allowing more than 4 digits and more than 2 char (I given exact number in pattern)..what's wrong in my pattern?

Still I want this code for textfield (showing error message while typing in textfield until correct format is entered ) what event i have to use for textfield?

Answer (score 0):

- You can set "pattern" (regex) to the input field. In this case it'd be something like `pattern="[0-9Aa]{4}\s?[0-9Aa]{2}"`.
- Then you must set `oninvalid` event listener to the input field. This will fire when pattern match is not met. e.g `oninvalid="showInvalidFormatMsg()"` or preferrably `fieldElem.addEventListener("invalid", showInvalidFormatMsg)`;
- After this you can either use built-in tooltip with [setCustomValidity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Constraint_API%27s_element.setCustomValidity%28%29) function or just display as a text in DOM in that `showInvalidFormatMsg`

I'm unable to write working code atm. But if you're unable to follow these instructions and no-one has answered with full code, I try to find some free spot to help you with this.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I tried like this                                                      var pattern="[0-9Aa]{4}\s?[0-9Aa]{2}";                                          postalcodetextfield.addEventListener('invalid',function(e){             while(postalcodetextfield.value!=pattern){                                     var error=Ti.UI.createLabel({text:'inavlid format:1234AA'....}               win.add(error);}   });     but not working